# How to use gdb python debugging extension inside virtualenv

Tags: python, gdb, virtualenv

I'm running ubuntu, and installed the python-dbg package. When trying to use the installed version directly everything works great:

```
$ gdb python2.7-dbg
GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4-2012.04-0ubuntu2.1) 7.4-2012.04
---x snipped x---
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/python2.7-dbg...done.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /usr/bin/python2.7-dbg
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:39:25)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x00007ffff6997743 in __select_nocancel () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:82
82      ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) py-bt (<--- works, just has nothing to do)
(gdb)
```

So, I've been building a virtualenv using the package's binary `python2.7-dbg` (since some libraries need recompiling), using this command line:

```
~$ virtualenv ved -p /usr/bin/python2.7-dbg
```

Its all working fine, but when I'm using gdb inside the virtualenv, atleast the python pretty printers stop working:

```
~$ . ved/bin/activate
(ved)~$ gdb python
GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4-2012.04-0ubuntu2.1) 7.4-2012.04
---x snipped x---
Reading symbols from /home/itai/ved/bin/python...done.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/itai/ved/bin/python
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:39:25)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x00007ffff6997743 in __select_nocancel () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:82
82      ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) py-bt
Undefined command: "py-bt".  Try "help". (<---- PROBLEM)
(gdb)
```

Am I missing something within my virtualenv?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've solved the problem by using strace on gdb, grepping the "open" syscalls.

It seems that gdb makes a search for python-gdb.py in several paths it guesses (according to the python binary), and whenever the file is not found it just fails silently.

Eventually the way to solve the problem is to link `/usr/lib/debug/usr/bin/python2.7-gdb.py` into the env's bin directory. The name of the link should be `<python binary name>-gdb.py`, being in my case `python2.7-dbg-gdb.py` (...).

After that, everything seems to work.

Comment: I had to put a line in my .gdbinit file as well:

`add-auto-load-safe-path /opt/hass-dbg/bin/python3-dbg-gdb.py`

Answer (score 7):

@itai's answer only partially worked for me on Ubuntu Trusty (14.04). I found a couple of other things worked better:

`sudo apt-get install python2.7-dbg`

then, in the virtualenv:

```
. bin/activate
mkdir bin/.debug
ln -s /usr/lib/debug/usr/bin/python2.7-gdb.py bin/.debug/python-gdb.py
ln -s /usr/lib/debug/usr/bin/python2.7 bin/.debug/

gdb --args bin/python2.7 ...
```

This helped gdb find the python debugging symbols as well as the py-bt etc commands.

Comment: I found (under ubuntu 14.04) it is important that the file under `.debug` is `python2.7`. I tried it with `python` (w/o 2.7) since virtualenv's `bin/python2.7` points to `bin/python`, but that didn't seem to work. (Which is what this answer says! But I outsmarted myself.)

Comment: `ln -sf /usr/lib/debug/usr/bin/ /my/virtualenv/bin/.debug` works too

Answer (score 2):

In Debian 11 with Python 3.7, gdb debugging works out of the box inside virtualenv.

Make sure that you created the venv with the same Python3 version than the `python3-dbg` package version installed.

In case symbols don't load correctly, rebuild the venv from scratch and try again.

Comment: On Ubuntu 22.04.1, it was sufficient to `apt install python3-dbg` and `python3-dbg -m venv ./env-name`.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 12.04, @craigds's answer was very helpful but didn't get me quite all the way there: I was still running into:

```
IOError: invalid Python installation: unable to open /path/to/venv/lib/python2.7/config_d/Makefile (No such file or directory)
```

Fixed that, then I ran into:

```
IOError: invalid Python installation: unable to open /path/to/venv/local/include/python2.7_d/pyconfig.h (No such file or directory)
```

So the full steps for me to fix up my virtualenv were:

```
source /path/to/venv/bin/activate
mkdir /path/to/venv/bin/.debug
ln -s /usr/lib/debug/usr/bin/python2.7-gdb.py /path/to/venv/bin/.debug/python-gdb.py
ln -s /usr/lib/debug/usr/bin/python2.7 /path/to/venv/bin/.debug/
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/config_d/ /path/to/venv/lib/python2.7/config_d
ln -s /usr/include/python2.7_d/ /path/to/venv/local/include/python2.7_d
ln -s /usr/lib/debug/usr/bin/python2.7-gdb.py /path/to/venv/bin/python-gdb.py
```