# See stacktrace of hanging Python in futex(..., FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|...)

Tags: python, debugging, freeze, futex

A Python process hangs in futex():

```
root@pc:~# strace -p 9042
strace: Process 9042 attached
futex(0x1e61900, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, NULL, ffffffff
```

I want to see the stacktrace if the hanging process.

Unfortunately ctrl-c does not work :-(

How can I see the stacktrace if Python hangs like this?

Comment: Just attach gdb to the process, or run pstack if you have it installed. Or `kill -SEGV` the process and examine the core, if you don't need to keep it alive.

Comment: @Useless I want to see the stacktrace of the python code. Not the stacktrace of the Python interpreter (c code). I looked at pstack, AFAIK pstack prints the latter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. install the gdb python extensions if needed for your system (see [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb) for example, or look at your distro documentation)
2. attach gdb to your hung process
3. run

   ```
   (gdb) py-bt
   ```

   instead of regular `bt` to get the Python backtrace

Comment: After doing the `ln -s ...` commands from another answer, and running gdb as root it worked. Here the other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30430059/633961